# HTML mode that closes tags

Tags: html

Regular HTML mode doesn't close tags. Or, if it does, I haven't found out how.

Transitioning out of Sublime Text, I am searching for an HTML markup mode that will close tags intelligently.

The HTML mode that came with my Emacs (on Ubuntu) can open tags automatically, but does not have a shortcut to close them (like Sublime does when you start typing greater than followed by a forward slash).

Comment: Emacs tells me that `C-c C-e` runs the command `sgml-close-tag`

Comment: `web-mode` should do

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With the default HTML mode as of Emacs 24.4, you can get the same behavior as Sublime Text (automatic insertion of the closing tag if you type `</`) by putting the following line in your init file:

```
(setq sgml-quick-keys 'close)
```

Out of the box, pressing `C-c /` or `C-c C-e` or `C-c /` inserts a closing tag (the whole `</foo>`).

You can find out about these keys by typing `C-h m` while editing an HTML file. This displays the list of mode-specific key bindings. Look for something relevant there — the keys are bound to a command called `sgml-close-tag`. The binding `C-c /` is also mentioned in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/HTML-Mode.html#HTML-Mode).

Finding out about the `</` behavior is harder: it's missing both from the manual and from the self-documentation. Pressing `C-h k /` tells you that `/` is bound to `sgml-slash`, and that it “behaves electrically” (that's Emacs-speak for “it inserts some stuff automatically”) when `sgml-quick-keys` is non-nil, but to find out about `close` you need to look at the source code.

Note that there are other HTML modes for Emacs and they may do things completely differently.

Answer (score 6):

Install web-mode, http://web-mode.org/. It is the most complete mode for web pages and does contain what it calls HTML tag auto closing.